# Grails 3 flush hibernate session causes NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, csv, grails, grails-orm

I'd like to know if you can help me with an error I am getting when inserting data to the database from a CSV file.

- Grails 3.2.4
- java version "1.8.0_111"
         Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
         Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
- Mysql 5.6.29
- Hibernate 5.1.1

The thing is that I am reading a CSV file and processing it in batches.
Since hibernate caches all objects in memory, after a certain amount of records I do a:

```
private void cleanUpGorm() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
}
```

This is to avoid the known performance issue when a lot of objects are stored into memory.

The thing is that with some CSV files (4 of 15), I get a NullPointerException when calling to session.flush() (with session not being null).
Those CSV files don't have any weird thing, the encoding is OK, no bad characters, etc.

I have two methods:

```
@NotTransactional
void loadDataFromCSV() {
   // Group the CSV lines into groups of 1000.
  loadBatch(myGroupOfLines)
}

// No annotation here.. I assume that by default is Transactional
void loadBatch(myGroupOfLines) {

   // Iterate over myGroupOfLines Inserting or updating the entries in the db.

  // Clean GORM cache
  if(index > 0 && index % CLEAN_GORM_CACHE_FREQUENCY == 0) {
      log.info "**** Cleaning GORM cache ****"
     cleanUpGorm()
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate if you can guide me to fix this issue, since I am trying to find a solution since a few days now.

The detailed NPE I'm getting is:

```
2017-01-19 18:00:52,440 - ERROR: GrailsExceptionResolver - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/admin/upload - parameters:
entity: OCEAN_COSTS
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.BatchFetchQueue.removeBatchLoadableEntityKey(BatchFetchQueue.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
        at maersk.calculator.api.MaritimeTransportationService$$EQ8n1X8K.cleanUpGorm(MaritimeTransportationService.groovy:401)
        at maersk.calculator.api.MaritimeTransportationService$__tt__loadBatch_closure10$$EQ8n1X8K.doCall(MaritimeTransportationService.groovy:227)
        at maersk.calculator.api.MaritimeTransportationService$$EQ8n1X8K.$tt__loadBatch(MaritimeTransportationService.groovy:200)
        at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
        at maersk.calculator.api.MaritimeTransportationService$$EQ8n1X8K.loadDataFromCSV(MaritimeTransportationService.groovy:139)
        at maersk.calculator.api.UploadController.triggerJob(UploadController.groovy:88)
        at maersk.calculator.api.UploadController.saveFile(UploadController.groovy:55)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT**

Well, actually I could isolate the problem and it is inside the loadBatch method.
It seems it is related to [#9290](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9290)

The error happens in the following piece of code:

```
mtc = new MaritimeTransportationCharge(charge, amount, currency, container, mt)
mt.addToCharges(mtc)
if(!mt.save()) {
    errors.add("Error in line $line: Invalid charge for container ${container}.\nErrors: ${Utils.getEntityErrors(mtc)}")
}
```

It seems that the associations are not being aligned anymore (as of Grails 2) and something is happening, maybe the child object is invalid.

The relationships are:

```
MaritimeTransportation hasMany: MaritimeTransportationCharges
MaritimeTransportationCharge belongsTo: MaritimeTransportation
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding SQL logging in application.yml

```
environments:
  local:
    dataSource:
        logSql: true
        formatSql: true
```

What I have seen from upgrading to grails 3 is that some of the automatic table mapping done by GORM can be wrong, so check that the tables its using in the logs to do any joins are correct. If you see that they are incorrect you can explicitly set them in your domain class e.g

```
MaritimeTransportationCharges joinTable: [name:"join_table_name", key: "key", column: "column"]
```